# Loading resource files with AngleSharp

Tags: c#, html-parsing, anglesharp

I imported the nuget packages for AngleSharp and AngleSharp.Scripting.Javascript into an empty project to see if it is possible to parse html from webpages after javascript/css is applied (like a headless browser).

I'm using http://pycoders.com/archive/ (which navigates to a newsletter archive which is populated using javascript in the browser) as a test url.

The basic sample scripts which show inline javascript functionality work for me and the javascript is processed after the html is loaded etc... but loading an actual webpage with `var document = await browseingContext.OpenAsync(new Url("http://pycoders.com/archive/"), CancellationToken.None);` is not processing scripts/css which is loaded from external file resources.

An attempt to debug the issue resulted in me implementing the IResourceLoader interface as a copy of the default ResourceLoader included in AngleSharp in my own project and it seems that favicon resource response streams are returned for the website but the first style resource file (https://s3.amazonaws.com/pycoders2/css/bootstrap.css) is not loaded into the ResponseStream by the WebRequest.

```
public async Task<IResponse> RequestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...

     _http.BeginGetResponse(ReceiveResponse, null);
     await _completed.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);

     if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        return null;

    return GetResponse();
}
```

For the css resource file above the running code gets to the line `_http.BeginGetResponse(ReceiveResponse, null);` but the `RecieveResponse` method is never called.

I hope someone can help me with loading resources in AngleSharp as it seems like a descent html parser and the javascript/css pre-processing would top it off nicely, removing my need for phantomjs and Selenium.

EDIT:

further details on the currently running resource tasks when the html would be rendered are as follows:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/pycoders2/img/favicon.ico - RanToCompletion

https://s3.amazonaws.com/pycoders2/img/favicon.ico - RanToCompletion

https://s3.amazonaws.com/pycoders2/css/bootstrap.css - WaitingForActivation

https://s3.amazonaws.com/pycoders2/css/main.css - WaitingForActivation

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,900 - RanToCompletion

https://s3.amazonaws.com/pycoders2/img/header.png - WaitingForActivation

http://us4.campaign-archive1.com/generate-js/?u=9735795484d2e4c204da82a29&fid=1817&show=200 - RanToCompletion

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js - RanToCompletion

https://s3.amazonaws.com/pycoders2/js/bootstrap.min.js - WaitingForActivation

Comment: What config are you using? Also are you using the latest version of AngleSharp (v0.8.6) or one of the previous versions? SSL may be the reason why your file is not loaded. Since AngleSharp is PCL it can only provide the (crappy) `HttpWebRequest` with limited options. Unfortunately it is not possible to use SSL and / or GZIP reliably with it - hence it is just a default implementation with limited capabilities (better than nothing).

Comment: As an additional remark: The AngleSharp.Scripting.JavaScript package is available, yes, but it currently highly experimental and far from being production ready. I try to make it better in the future, but honestly, it is a huge effort and the project is lacking contributors. Hence I don't know when I will call it production ready.

Comment: hey Florian thanks for the reply. The config i'm using is this: var config = Configuration.Default.WithJavaScript().WithCss().WithCookies().With(new ASLoaderService(GetHttpRequesters())); which is the same as the config in the examples from github apart from I load my own implemented LoaderService which mostly is a copy of your default LoaderService for debugging

Answer (score 1):

At the moment my best guess is that the integrated HTTP requester can't handle the SSL certificate (had this problem in the past; for most pages it works - for some it does not). Since the AWS instance is also accepting "http" requests, can you try modifying the URL to `http://s3.amazonaws.com/pycoders2/css/bootstrap.css`? As an evil hack you can just wrap the existing HTTP requester and use it with URLs modified from *https* to *http*.

Does it work then?

Remark: I tried to allow all SSL requests. This is possible in the regular .NET version of the `HttpWebRequest`. Unfortunately the PCL version does not come with such options.

Comment: i added a handler to `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` which returns true for the ssl validation and added an static `IEnumerable<Task>` to my ResourceLoader class so I can use `Task.WaitAll` before continuing to display the javascript rendered html but the application hangs at `Task.WaitAll`

Comment: see my edit for current task statuses, all of which are amazonaws urls

Comment: Its hard to say something without much code (MWE to demo the problem would be great), but just a simple question: how does the application / requests perfom if you drop the `WaitAll`? Are the requests done properly?

Comment: @John Earnshaw any solution？